# Why is it showing combination object instead of combination.I want to print all the possible combo of all lenghts

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools

**I want to print possible combinations to a string of all lengths**

```
import itertools

string = input()

l1 = [ ]

for i in string:
    l1.append(i)

combo = []

combo = [itertools.combinations(l1,i) for i in range(len(l1))]  #i want to resolve this line

print(combo)
```

Comment: combination returns an object. you need to wrap it in list()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
import itertools
string = input()
l1 = [i for i in string ]

combo = [list(itertools.combinations(l1,i)) for i in range(len(l1))] 
print(combo)
```